# Special linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Special linear transformations are matrices with determinant equal to 1.

What additional properties do such transformations have compared to "regular" linear transformations?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group

Comment: Geometrically, applying such a  matrix to a 2D figure doesn't change the area of the figure (or to a 3D figure, it doesn't change the volume).

Comment: @Daniel Montealegre, thanks for the link. Frankly, I searched in Russian only, so I didn't find this obvious link.

Answer (score 1):

For example, for $A\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ one has the property
$$ A+A^{-1}=\mathrm{Tr}\,A\cdot \mathbf{1}_2$$
which is often useful, and also $\mathrm{Tr}\,A=\mathrm{Tr}\,A^{-1}$.